# Track records that exceed defined value and its multiples

Tags: sql-server

I have a table "Items" with records that shows a progress through time of a single item. One of the columns is numeric value (DeltaLimit) showing price change compared to the starting point of the records.

I also have a defined @Limit variable. I need to select the record where DeltaLimit exceeds @Limit for the first time, and if the DeltaLimit exceeds multiples of the @Limit, I need to do the same.

Basically, I need the first row where DeltaLimit exceeds @Limit, the fist row where DeltaLimit exceeds 2*@Limit, the first row where DeltaLimit exceeds 3*@Limit etc.

Source data - @Limit = 0.5

> Name | DeltaLimit
>   Ex1 | 0.4
>   Ex2 | 0.6
>   Ex3 | 0.9
>   Ex4 | 1.1
>   Ex5 | 1.3

Desired output

> Name | DeltaLimit
>   Ex2 | 0.6
>   Ex4 | 1.1

The only thing I managed to do was to get the first row that exceeds the @Limit itself with the following select, but I have no idea how to get the rows the exceeds the following multiples of @Limit. Any help would be greatly aprreciated.

```
   select * from Items
   where DeltaLimit = (select top 1 DeltaLimit from Items where DeltaLimit < @Limit);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the DeltaLimit by the Limit and get your Row_Number using the result.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY convert(int, DeltaLimit / @Limit) ORDER BY DeltaLimit) Rn  
    FROM    Table1
    WHERE   DeltaLimit > @Limit
) t 
WHERE t.Rn = 1
```

[Rextester.com demo](http://rextester.com/GOE67189)

Comment: that's a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a projection relation for the delta limit multipliers... basically a temporary table with values {`.5, 1.0, ,1.5, 2.0`} etc, up the highest needed by the data. I'll leave that as an exercise and just call it `#ScaledLimits` in the below code. Once you have it, you can use it like this:

```
SELECT results.*
FROM #ScaledLimits sl
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM Items 
    WHERE Items.DeltaLimit > sl.DeltaLimit 
    ORDER BY Items.DeltaLimit 
) results
```

See it in action here:

> http://rextester.com/QIP53078